# Es posible cambiar el color de un checkbox al ser seleccionado?

Tags: laravel, laravelcollective

Tengo el siguiente checkbox y me gustaría que en vez de color azul (Primary en bootstrap) me muestre otro (Color Info).

```
{{ Form::checkbox('availability[]', 1) }}
```

Comment: el 4to argumento es para darle extras, probá con `{{ Form::checkbox('availability[]', 1, null, [ 'class' => 'checkbox-info' ] ) }} `

Comment: Hola, no... No funcionó.. Ya había intentado con `{{ Form::checkbox('availability[]', 1, null, [ 'class' => 'text-info' ] ) }} ` y `{{ Form::checkbox('availability[]', 1, null, [ 'class' => 'bg-info' ] ) }} ` y tampoco

Comment: puede q la versión de bootstrap no traiga estilados para checkboxes? fijate como arma el html con la `class=checkbox-info` y si es compatible con este css ( la class va en el div contenedor del checkbox+label ) http://embed.plnkr.co/B4BatpwxCa2cBoYo0oEQ/

Comment: Gracias, funciona pero debo hacer unos cambios. Agradecido